# CodePush - Create an app for each OS you target

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

[CodePush registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pSfa.png)

I'm registering with CodePush for a React Native project. Step number 3 says Register your app with the service. In order to let the service know about your app, simply register it using a recognizable name. Create an app for each OS you target.

Does this mean I need to react-native init two separate projects, one with suffix -Android and one with -iOS?

I apologize if this is a stupid question but it's not clear what CodePush is asking me to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think that's the way to do it. I have also created two apps for codepush ios and android.I push code on each platform when they I need to.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. CodePush is a part of App Center which currently supports one app per OS/platform combination. In the future you'll see apps brought together under app groups, but for now you target iOS and Android separately.